# Parsing gateway ip from `/proc/net/route` in a docker container

Tags: php, parsing, linux, docker

In try to replicate the outcome of the following command sequence using php:

```
netstat -rn | grep "^0.0.0.0 " | cut -d " " -f10
```

I did this using a PHP script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php

<?php

/**
 *  Xdebug ip detector for docker
 *  Copyright (C) 2023  Dimitrios Desyllas

 *  This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 *  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 *  the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 *  (at your option) any later version.

 *  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 *  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 *  GNU General Public License for more details.

 *  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 *  along with this program.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

$matches = [];
preg_match("/^\w*\s(00000000)\s(\w*)/m",file_get_contents("/proc/net/route"),$matches);

// At regex each () is also matxched seperately. In my case I have 2 matched groups therefore the secodn match is my ip hex encoded
$ip = $matches[2];
$ip = str_split($ip,2);
$ip = array_reverse($ip);

$ip = array_reduce($ip,function($acc,$item){
    return $acc.intval($item,16).".";
},"");

$ip = rtrim($ip,'.');

echo $ip;
```

Is this the way to parse the ip directly from `/proc/net/route`?
This script is intended to be run inside a docker container that also ships with PHP and xdebug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Reading the gateway IP

I'm not an expert of reading routing info, but:

- [Linuxtopia's article on Linux Filesystem Hierarchy](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_beginner_books/linux_filesystem/proc.html) confirms that `/proc/net/route` contains the *Kernel routing table*.
- The format assumed by the posted code matches what I get on recent Linux machine, and also on a pretty old Linux machine.

So I think your method is fine.

Another alternative to reading from `/proc/net/route` would be to call the `netstat` command as you mention in your post and parse its output.

#### Reading the gateway IP as a hex string

This functionality seems a good candidate to wrap into a function, having this "shape":

```
# Returns the gateway IP address as a hex string of reversed bytes,
# for example 0100A8C0, or null if not possible
function read_gateway_ip_hex_string() {
  # ...
}
```

I find the `preg_match` solution a bit hacky.
I find it more natural to consider the structure of the file as a table with columns, and get the 2nd column when the 1st column is 00000000:

```
function read_gateway_ip_hex_string() {
  $fn = fopen("/proc/net/route", "r");
  
  while(! feof($fn))  {
    $line = fgets($fn);
    $parts = preg_split("/\s+/", $line);
    if ($parts[1] == "00000000") {
      $ip_hex_string = $parts[2];
      break;
    }
  }
 
  fclose($fn);

  return $ip_hex_string;
}
```

It's more verbose than the posted code,
but I think it's easier to understand how it works.

#### Converting a hex string to dotted decimals

Similarly to getting the hex string,
I think this is also a good opportunity to wrap this functionality into a reusable and testable function:

```
function ip_hex_string_to_dotted_decimals($ip_hex_string) {
    $ip_bytes = array_reverse(
        array_map(fn($s): int => intval($s, 16),
            str_split($ip_hex_string, 2)));

    return implode('.', $ip_bytes);
}
```

Instead of the `array_reduce` + `rtrim` combo, this one maps array items and then joins them, which I find easier to understand.

#### Putting it together

From the building blocks in functions,
the main part of the program becomes:

```
$ip_hex_string = read_gateway_ip_hex_string();

if (is_null($ip_hex_string)) {
    # TODO: do something helpful!
} else {
    $ip = ip_hex_string_to_dotted_decimals($ip_hex_string);
    echo $ip;
}
```

Comment: well I wanted to use as a small script and not part of a major app in my case. Also docker container routes are small.

Answer (score 3):

## It is wise to ensure an array has a key before dereferencing it

After the call to `preg_match()` the code accesses key `2`:

> ```
> $ip = $matches[2];
> ```

While it may be improbable, it *may* be plausible that there is no value at index `2` and in that scenario a warning would be thrown:

> Warning: Undefined array key 2

It is a good habit to ensure to guard against cases where an array doesn't have a key - perhaps with [conditional logic](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php), [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce) or a [null-safe operator](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php#nullsafe-operator).

## Follow PHP Standards Recommendations

While there are no *de jure* rules about readability conventions and it is up to individuals/teams to decide their conventions, idiomatic PHP code often follows the [PHP Standards Recommendations](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/) - e.g. [PSR-12: Extended Coding Style](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/).

> ```
> $ip = str_split($ip,2);
> ```

This goes against PSR-12 section 4.5:

> #### [4.5 Method and Function Arguments](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#45-method-and-function-arguments)
>
> In the argument list, there MUST NOT be a space before each comma, and there MUST be one space after each
> comma.

```
$ip = str_split($ip, 2);
```

And

> ```
> return $acc.intval($item,16).".";
> ```

This goes against PSR-12 section 6.2:

> #### [6.2. Binary operators](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#62-binary-operators)
>
> All binary [arithmetic](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php), [comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), [assignment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php), [bitwise](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php), [logical](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php), [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php), and [type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php) operators MUST be preceded and followed by at least one space:

Binary operators are typically separated with a space on both sides:

```
return $acc . intval($item,16) . ".";
```

## Variable is over-written

There are five assignments to `$ip`:

> ```
> $ip = $matches[2];
> $ip = str_split($ip,2);
> $ip = array_reverse($ip);
>
> $ip = array_reduce($ip,function($acc,$item){
>     return $acc.intval($item,16).".";
> },"");
>
> $ip = rtrim($ip,'.');
> ```

Over-writing `$ip` each time prevents re-using a value, which may not be a problem, though the meaning and type of the variable would change. For readability it would be better to use different names for each assignment.

Comment: So for the `$ip = $matches[2];` what approach would you reccomend?